# Cleaned hard drive, reinstalled OSX- now all my iTunes purchased music is gone

Tags: itunes

When I try to download already purchased songs I get this message:

[image]

Will I be charged once more if I click "Buy"?

Ps. When I click "Check for available downloads" I just get the message

[image]

Psps. It might just be that the new Itunes is buggy. I get this startup-screen, but when I click "scan for music", nothing happens.

[image]

Comment: Did you have iCloud enabled? Did you make a backup before cleaning the hard drive?

Comment: No; I just thought it was a no-brainer that Apple should keep track of what I purchased. I mean, it must be in my account somewhere.

Comment: You can redownload apps but AFAIK you can't redownload music (without iCloud at least). That's why you get a dialog box reminding you of backup up your purchases if you buy music.

Comment: I tried repurchasing an album. Will see how it goes and notify you all.

Comment: I was charged anew! Waah!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sign in to itunes, click iTunes Store. In the right hand column there is a link to "purchased"

[image]

This opens to a screen that looks like this:

[image: Purchased Screen Shot]

You can re-download everything from there as long as its all on the single apple ID.

Good Luck!

Comment: This is probably how it is supposed to work in theory so UV

Answer (score 0):

When repurchasing from the iTunes store I was charged once more, so do not use the "repurchase" option.

Only US users are allowed to redownload music. Thank god for torrent sites.

Source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3103354?start=15&tstart=0

Ps. iTunes refunded my money so all is well.

Psps. will update when/if I get to the bottom of this.